# LINQ Query for a Nested Class

Tags: c#, linq

As a newbie with C# and LINQ, I'm rather confused with the implementation of a particular query I'm attempting. I have an array of one particular class called `Session`. One of the properties of this class is an array of `ActiveConnection`, another class. Each `ActiveConnection` contains an enumeration for `ProcessType`.

Here's the goal: I need to determine which `Session` objects from said array contain an `ActiveConnection` with `ProccessType.Guest`. After plenty of fiddling, I've got my code below (which doesn't even compile anymore).

```
// Creating my array Session[]
var sessions = GetSessions();

var busySessions = from sessions
                   where sessions.ActiveConnections.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest
                   select sessions;

// Do other stuff with this array of busy sessions
```

Clearly, I don't understand how to implement a LINQ query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a nested query for this (since `ActiveConnections` is a collection):

```
var result = sessions.Where(session => session.ActiveConnections.Any(conn => conn.ProcessType == ProcessType.Guest));
```

This will return all sessions where `Guest` is in the `ActiveConnections` list (which is what you *said*). To do what your code did, you would need:

```
var result = sessions.Where(session => session.ActiveConnections.All(conn => conn.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest));
```

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var busySessions = sessions.ToList().Where(s => s.ActiveConnections.Any(ac => ac.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest)).Select();
```

OR

```
var busySessions = (from s in sessions
                   where s.ActiveConnections.Any(ac => ac.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest)
                   select sessions).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable in the `from` clause, to represent each item in the source:

```
from session in GetSessions()
```

Then, you execute a subquery on the entire set of active connections:

```
where session
    .ActiveConnections
    .Any(connection => connection.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest)
```

Finally, you select the sessions that meet the criteria:

```
select session
```

Full query:

```
from session in GetSessions()
where session
    .ActiveConnections
    .Any(connection => connection.ProcessType != ProcessType.Guest)
select session
```